# Why won't Confluence let me configure my Bamboo gadgets?

Tags: confluence, bamboo

I've integrated my Bamboo with Confluence by adding Application Links in both directions (two links, each in one direction). I then added Bamboo's gadget feed to Confluence, so I could use the Bamboo gadgets.
Now when I try to add any Bamboo gadget as a macro, they are shown, so they should at least have been found and integrated. 
When I try to configure it, however, I can only configure the width, margin and the author. All other properties are seemingly set in the preview, which is empty, so I can't configure or use these gadgets.
Any ideas as to why that is? 
(The gadget-URL should be correct, as the gadgets are recognized by Confluence. I just can't configure or add them.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arose because I was using Chrome. When I tried to configure the gadgets with Firefox it worked fine. The reason for this is Chrome's default security setting interfering with my current Confluence setup (as explained [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMKB/Bamboo+Gadgets+doesn%27t+show+content+on+some+browsers)).

By allowing Chrome to show the insecure content, I was able to configure and add the Bamboo gadgets.